# Alternate Database Connection in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

Please someone help me - I have a problem.

I'm trying to code an alternate database for a program I am writing in C#. You see on the website I managed to do it with an if..

This is my php code:

```
//database connection
$conexion = @mysqli_connect("localhost","todo","todo","dbdaq");

//if mainserver connection is not made then it connects to secondary server

if (!$conexion){
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("192.168.0.12","todo","","dbdaq");
}
```

And that works in PHP, but when I try to write something like that in C#, I can't manage to do it.

Here is my database connection class in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ComunicacionCSharp
{
    class ConexionBD
    {
        public static MySqlConnection ObtenerConexion()
        {
            MySqlConnection Conectar = new MySqlConnection("Server =localhost; database = dbdaq ; Userid = root; password =");
            return Conectar;
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: this class is called from my main GUI interface.

```
namespace ComunicacionCSharp 
{ 
    public partial class Login : Form 
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = ConexionBD.ObtenerConexion(); 
        public string usuario; 

        public Login() 
        { 
            InitializeComponent(); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me? I use to have another version of the database connection with an error message if the connection is not found, but I left coding in C# for a while and could not find that piece of code anymore, and I don't remember how to do it :(

Comment: in the C# code, you have a static method however you are not showing how or where you are calling this method, also are you familiar with how to store the connection string inside of a .Config file ?

Comment: this is another snippet of code, this is my main interface code where i call the method

Comment: namespace ComunicacionCSharp
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = ConexionBD.ObtenerConexion();

        public string usuario;

        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

Comment: I edited your question and added your comments to your original question

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_connect` returns a handle to an open connection and in your C# code you pass an unopened connection. You must change a bit your code, something like this:

```
public static MySqlConnection ObtenerConexion()
{

    MySqlConnection Conectar = null;

    try
    {
        Conectar = new MySqlConnection(yourFirstConnectionString);
        Conectar.Open();
    }
    catch
    {
        try
        {
            Conectar = new MySqlConnection(yourSecondConnectionString);
            Conectar.Open();
        }
        catch{ }
    }

    return Conectar;

}
```

Remember to check the connection wherever you use it, if both connections fail it will return null.

Comment: thanks gusman, ill try it later today when i get homes, i have my other server there.

Comment: didnt mean to, clicked by accident and then it said that i had to wait a certain amount of time to change it again and i forgot to get to it again.

Comment: im bearly trying the code but it doesnt conect to the secondary database